Finite Difference Grid for Asian option + python
I am trying to write python code to price an Asian option (call payoff at maturity = avg(S(T)) - E, i.e. average of the asset price - strike) with FDM and grid. I have the following code, but the result is about 10% off what I get with MC (checked against QuantLib). Can anyone help me spotting the problem? Thanks!
grid = pd.DataFrame(grid, index=s, columns=np.around(t, 3))
# Final payoff at maturity for a Call Option
for i in range(NAS+1):
    average_S = (s[i] + option.S0) / 2  # Arithmetic average of stock price
    grid.iloc[i, NTS] = max(average_S - E, 0)  # Payoff for an Asian Call Option

# Fill the grid
for k in range(len(t)-2, -1, -1):  # Backward direction in time
    for i in range(1, len(s)-1):
        delta = (grid.iloc[i+1, k+1] - grid.iloc[i-1, k+1]) / (2*ds)
        gamma = (grid.iloc[i+1, k+1] - 2*grid.iloc[i, k+1] + grid.iloc[i-1, k+1]) / (ds**2)
        theta = (-0.5 * vol**2 * s[i]**2 * gamma) - (r*s[i]*delta) + (r*grid.iloc[i, k+1])
        
        grid.iloc[i, k] = grid.iloc[i, k+1] - dt*theta
    
    # Boundary condition at S = 0
    grid.iloc[0, k] = grid.iloc[0, k+1] * np.exp(-r*dt)
    
    # Boundary condition at S = infinity
    grid.iloc[-1, k] = 2*grid.iloc[-2, k] - grid.iloc[-3, k]


No one can help on this?
